How do I save a layer overlaying another as a .tif file?
I have a layer, with points and another layer with the original orthomosaic. I would like to merge the two layers and generate a new orthomosaic from this union:
My layers:

How do I save a layer overlaying another as a .tif file?

Make a layout with the points over the raster and export it as a tif.

Your layers screenshot contains two rasters, but no points.  Please edit your question to clarify what you want to overlay.
